# NGXS get id of object

Tags: angular, ngxs

I writing app, that i can save events in mongodb by using ngxs where I injected serverService. When I'm sending event I do that without id ,because mongo adding id automatically, just wait for it and then patch state. (insertEvent returng id then I look for whole Event and fetch that)

```
@Action(CreateEvent)
    createEvent({ getState, patchState }: StateContext<EventStateModel>, { event }: CreateEvent) {
        this.eventsService.insertEvent(event)
        .pipe(map(id => id['id']))
        .pipe(switchMap(id => id ? this.eventsService.getEventById(id) : empty() ))
        .subscribe(event => {
            const { events } = getState();

            patchState({
                events: [
                    ...events,
                    event
                ]
            });
        });
    }
```

But after add event I want to get this Id, to direct to event view. I don't know how to get event with id.

```
createRandom(){
    this.store.dispatch(
      new CreateEvent(EventFactory.create())  
    )
  }
```

When I'm try to use action handling ,it always returns me event with mock id by me.

```
this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(CreateEvent)).subscribe((ev) => {
   console.log(ev)
})
```

[Console Log return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNFSo.png)

Comment: which approach did you choose? 
I want to avoid dispatching actions in my actions ... 
but it seems to be the cleanest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the action stream in this case will return the the payload of the action you dispatched (with the mock ID).

I can see two options here:

1. Create a different action e.g. `EventCreated` that you can then subscribe to - and in this action payload, include the details (the ID) of what was just created.  Dispatch it after your `patch` operation.

or

2. in the current action stream pipe, use a `withLatestFrom` operator to grab the latest view of the state, and inspect the last `event` in your `events array to see what ID was generated.